# Hiding scrub/seek bar with HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, audio

Is there a good way to hide the scrub/seek bar on HTML5 audio elements? I know that removing `controls=` will hide it, but it also hides play/pause & duration timer which is not ideal.

I'm using [this](https://codepen.io/markhillard/pen/Hjcwu) playlist functionality which does use HTML5 audio.

Someone suggested removing the controls attribute & then creating the rest of the functions aside from the seek bar. I was surprised find that hiding just the seek isn't very easy for how robust the audio/video tags are. I've also seen a solution that disables the seek bar, but I specifically need it hidden from the user.

For this solution, I need almost no compatibility. It must work in the latest (as of June 2017) mobile Safari & that is the only requirement.

Comment: I think that *«Someone suggested removing the controls attribute & then creating the rest of the functions aside »* is the only answer.

Comment: I figured, just wondering if anyone had some insight on this. Thanks!